# Rectifying timeformat in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, casting, timestamp

I am working on third party data which I need to load into my postgresql database. I am running into problems where sometimes I get the time '24:00:30' when it actually should be '00:00:30'. This rejects the data.

I tried to cast but it did not work.

```
insert into stop_times_test trip_id, cast(arrival_time as time), feed_id, status
from   external_source;
```

Is there any way to convert to the correct one internally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may work for your case:

```
> select '0:0:0'::time + '24:00:30'::interval;
00:00:30
```

Answer (score 1):

Cast to interval, then cast to time:

```
SELECT '24:00:30'::interval::time
```

If you want to bulk load the data with `COPY` or mass `INSERT` make the target column data type `interval` and convert it to `time` later. This works out of the box:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ALTER col1 TYPE time;
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no magic way of doing it. No cast will help you. `24:00:30` is an invalid time. Period.

You could try adding that value on a varchar and then using regular expressions to update the right values and insert them on the right columns. This sort of things happen **a lot** when doing data transformation.